# Struts2 workflow/webflow plugin

Tags: struts2, workflow

I want a workflow/webflow plugin that needs to be integrated with an existing Struts2 application.

I found Struts-workflow-extension but looking in its source code I realized it is entirely based on the Struts1 and have there is no support for this plugin since 2003.

Basically my requirement is to handle the entire workflow through configurations that could be done at runtime. Spring webflow is also an option but it's much of a learning curve depending on the deadline that I have to meet.

So is there any workflow/webflow extension that can be easily integrated with Struts2?

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What about JBPM (http://www.jboss.org/jbpm/)? we use it...Have you tried it so far?

Comment: yes I have tried it.It gives u business process management and is very good in its domain but what I need is a webflow with 4 to 5 steps and these steps needs to be configurable.So jbpm doesn't quite fully fit in here or u can say it will overkill the situation.

Answer (score 1):

You can try https://github.com/aleksandr-m/struts2-actionflow which seems to be more up to date.